# Is there an alternative to Google Chart API QR Generator?

Tags: php, qr-code, google-visualization

Google Chart API QR Generator is deprecated and will not be supported after 2015. Does anyone know of a better alternative to this that I can use on PHP-based websites?

Comment: does it have to be an api? there are many php libraries to do this.

Comment: @Dagon I found some but I was worried they may restrict high volume API requests. That's why I am looking for a reliable one.

Comment: if you install a library locally there is no volume issue.

Comment: Yes. Do you know of a good library that you can recommend? I found one at Sourceforge.

Comment: try a few see what meets your needs, i don't like recommending scripts (to many variables)

Comment: I assume you're talking about PHPQRCode on Sourceforge? http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/index.php#demo - It's simple, it works. I've used it without any issues - give it a try and see if it meets your needs

Comment: @PerryW Yes that's the one. I will give it a try. I think it'll be good enough for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one that I have created.

https://github.com/edent/QR-Generator-PHP

Very easy to install on your own server.  No third party dependencies so no API limits :-)