# Deprecation of Google Infographics, QR Codes

Tags: google-api, google-visualization, qr-code

For the last 5 or so years if I have needed a QR code I have used the google APIs, yesterday for around 4 hours this service stopped. On investigation I found the service is now deprecated and a link to use Google Charts instead? I can not find any qr codes though?

[image: Warning: This API is deprecated. Please use the actively maintained Google Charts API instead. See our deprecation policy for details]

So my question is does anyone one know if Google maintaining an API to generate QR Codes? If so where can the documentation on this be found. Or has their been a definitive statement from Google to say they are not supporting it going forward.

The google API is really easy to use and has been reliable until now, example below.

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&chl=stuff

[image]

I found this post from a few years ago, I am not working in php sadly.
[Is there an alternative to Google Chart API QR Generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034664/is-there-an-alternative-to-google-chart-api-qr-generator)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Its been deprecated since 2015.  Think you had loads of warning.

Comment: @DaImTo I have edited the post so it is more of a cut and dry question, For production I have always used a self contained solution. Maybe off the back of this I will produce my own API to use.

Comment: i had the same issue with that google api, but i found this http://goqr.me/api/ is simple, and it works fine. You should try it.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the dynamic Google Charts Javascript library supports QR codes.  There are many alternative services that have been posted since its deprecation.

One such service is QuickChart, which is hosted at https://quickchart.io/ and also open source.